# Update the base view in PostgresDB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have created a view in the below manner in PostgresDB

```
create or replace view GEO_VIEW
as
 SELECT street,
    st.latitude_val,
    st.longitude_Val,
    st.location_name,
    st.vendor
from st_stat_tbl st 
join lt_stat_tbl lt on st.st_id = lt.lt_id
;
```

The issue is that this view is used in the definition of various other views.
Now, I need to update this view as below

```
create or replace view GEO_VIEW
as
 SELECT street,
    st.latitude_val,
    st.longitude_Val,
    st.loc_val as location_name,
    st.vendor
from st_stat_tbl st 
join lt_stat_tbl lt on st.st_id = lt.lt_id
;
```

I get the below error messages.

```
[Code: 0, SQL State: 2BP01]  ERROR: cannot drop view GEO_VIEW because other objects depend on it
```

Any idea how I can update this without having to recreate the underlying views.?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that without re-creating the referenced view. Just re-create all views in the correct order. This another good example why a proper schema migration concept (and tool) helps to make life easier

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: This error get when you are using this view in other views,  in return of functions, inside functions and etc.  You must firstly drop these functions, after then you can re-create this view. After recreating you can create dropped functions.